# Why does my compiler expect a ';' before '}' token at a label?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node {
   int number;
   string name;
   node* next;
};

int hash(string dna) {
   int i, sum=0;
   for (i=0; i<dna.size(); i++) {
      if (dna[i]=='A') {
      }
      else if (dna[i]=='C') {
         sum+=1;
      }
      else if (dna[i]=='G') {
         sum+=2;
      }
      else {
         sum+=3;
      }
   }
   cout << "Hash sum is " << sum << endl;
   return sum;
}

int main() {
   //input
   int dnalength, sublength;
   cin >> dnalength >> sublength;
   string sequence;
   cin >> sequence;
   //Declare array
   vector <node*> list(sublength*3+1);
   cout << "The list size is " << list.size() << endl;
   //Storing all substrings
   int index;
   for (index=0; index+sublength-1<dnalength; index++) {
      string temp = sequence.substr(index, sublength);
      cout << "Current substring is " << temp << endl;
      int value = hash(temp);
      if (list[value]==NULL) {
         //cout << "Null activated " << endl;
         //Node declaration
         node* ptr;
         ptr = new node;
         ptr->number=1;
         ptr->name=temp;
         ptr->next=NULL;

         list[value]=ptr;
      }
      else {
         node* ptr=list[value];
         while (ptr->next!=NULL) {
            if (ptr->name==temp) {
               ptr->number++;
               goto location;
            }
            ptr=ptr->next;
         }
         if (ptr->name==temp) {
            ptr->number++;
            goto location;
         }
         node* newptr;
         newptr = new node;
         newptr->number=1;
         newptr->name=temp;
         newptr->next=NULL;

         ptr->next=newptr;
location:
      }
      cout << "Success 1 loop " << endl;
   }
   cout << "Debug @ 3: " <<list[3]->name << list[3]->number << endl;
   cout << "Debug @ 3: " <<(list[3]->next)->name << (list[3]->next)->number << endl;

   int numofsub;
   cin >> numofsub;

   return 0;
}
```

Expected ';' before '}' token ??? At line 80:7, which is this part

```
         ptr->next=newptr;
location:
      }
```

I am at my wits end... I tried so many ways to debug, the problem has to do with the GOTO function, but I really really cannot see any issues with it!

Comment: A label (e.g. `location:`) *must* precede a statement.  Even `;` on its own will suffice.

Comment: _the problem has to do with the GOTO function_: frequently when using goto, this can be said :)

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html

Comment: A title should attempt to describe the problem, not how you feel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't. Replace:

```
      ptr->next=newptr;
location:
   }
```

with

```
      ptr->next=newptr;
location:;                   // <-- empty statement
   }
```

This is the grammar of the language: a statement must follow a label, at least an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard defines `labeled statement`. It means that the label can be only before a statement. The definition of the labeled statement (shortened) looks as

```
identifier : statement
```

So this construction

```
location:
      }
```

is invalid because the label does not precede any statement. 
If you want that the control would be passed to the end of a code block you can use a null statement. For example

```
location: ;
      }
```

From the C++ Standard

> A null statement is useful to carry a label just before the } of a compound statement and to
>       supply a null body to an iteration statement such as a while statement